# strtok() strcat() Unexpected output

Tags: c

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

int main(){
    int counter;
    char *token;
    char s[]={"I am John"};
    char con[256];
    token = strtok(s," ");
    while(token != NULL){
        if (counter==0){
            strcat(con,token);
            token = strtok(NULL," ");
            counter++;
        }else{
            strcat(con,token);
            token = strtok(NULL," ");
            strcat(con," ");
        }

    }
    printf("%s\n",con);
    return 0;
}`
```

`printf()`'s output is "I am John"
I would like the output to be "am John"

Comment: I initialize counter but the result is the same

Comment: Null terminate your array: `con[0] = '\0'`;

Comment: Also, you might need to add `if(token)` just before `strcat(con," ");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `strcat` expects the first argument to be null-terminated, which isn't guaranteed by declaring `con`, since its uninitialized. so the invocation of `strcat` is **undefined behavior**. Therefore your program is undefined behavior. Do

   ```
   con[0] = '\0';
   ```

   to resolve this issue.
2. `counter` is uninitialized. Using it in an expression is undefined behavior too.

Answer (score 3):

`counter` and array `con` is uninitialized . So it will lead to erroneous results.

Comment: I initialize counter but result is the same

Comment: @psofoklis11 Initialize con. Like `char con[256] = "";`